# localStorage in IE10 doesn't work

Tags: internet-explorer, null, local-storage

I'm using IE10 and I've got two tabs:
- Tab1: index.html
- Tab2: update.html

In tab2:

```
        var tel = getURLParameter('TELNR');
        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") { 
                     localStorage.setItem("telephone", "" + tel + ""); 
    }
```

In tab1:

```
                function handleStorage(oEvent) {
                   var telephone = localStorage.getItem("telephone");   
                   if (telephone != null) {
                      alert("New call from this phone number:" + telephone);
                   }
                };
            $(window).bind('storage', handleStorage);
```

I first open tab1 which waits for an event to occur. I then open tab2 passing on a given telephone number. The listener on tab1 is correctly triggered but telephone is null. If I refresh tab2, handleStorage is invoked this time with the correct number.

This works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.
Any clue?

Comment: a) What is `Storage` doing there and why are you checking it? b) Are you sure you are actually **changing** the value? `onStorage` only triggers when a stored value is **changed**. This seems to imply you are not setting it correctly the first time.

Comment: To play it safe I've removed the if statement                         if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined")  but there's no change. I am 100% certain I'm changing the value. The first time tab2 sets the value to X and tab1 understands that something was changed but when I retrieve the value I'm being returned "null". By the way, I've seen that if in tab1 I code this: var telephone = oEvent.originalEvent.newValue  I have the correct value so there's already a workaround. However I would like the localStorage solution to work correctly in the first place.

Comment: try use, instead of the onstorage event, the onstoragecommit event

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your scenario but be aware that IE is slower / later to populate localStorage than the other browsers on page load. I've addressed this by doing a soft page reload, location.reload() for IE after which localStorage data is then available during the subsequent page load.